# jasper reports axis lines thikness

Tags: java, jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

I am customizing the default charts generated by Jasper Reports and I cannot find the way to make the axis lines thicker.

So far I easily found examples to change the color:
http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11639 but this is easier to be changed by the editor.

I attach an image to illustrate the expected thickness compared to the current one.

[image: Current result]

This is my current customizer:

```
public void customize(JFreeChart jFreeChart, JRChart jrChart) {

    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) jFreeChart.getPlot();
    plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);


    BarRenderer barRenderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    barRenderer.setItemMargin(0.0);

    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    NumberFormat numberFormat= NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(numberFormat);
    rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(0.2);
    rangeAxis.setAutoRange(true); //make sure that fixed range is not set
}
```

GitHub: https://github.com/MichaelKnight/jaspertest.git

Comment: I fixed the formatting of code and removed the second request for off-site resources (this is a close reason). However the best place to find example's is on the jfreechart home page, specially the sample page (they have an application you can run and see tons of examples), to find the source code of example search some on internet or buy it from them.

Comment: Do you still have problems with this?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I was on sick leave and I couldn't test it yet. I hope I can do it along today. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the [Stroke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Stroke.html) of `CategoryAxis` and `NumberAxis` add the following code in your `customize`:

```
CategoryAxis categoryAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
categoryAxis.setAxisLineStroke(new BasicStroke(2f)); //see API link below for BasicStroke

NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setAxisLineStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
```

[BasicStroke API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html)